# How to get text entered in wxTextCtrl and assign it to a string variable?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl, wxformbuilder

I have the following GUI created in wxFormBuilder:

[image]

gui.h:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// C++ code generated with wxFormBuilder (version Oct 26 2018)
// http://www.wxformbuilder.org/
//
// PLEASE DO *NOT* EDIT THIS FILE!
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#pragma once

#include <wx/artprov.h    
#include <wx/xrc/xmlres.h    
#include <wx/intl.h    
#include <wx/string.h    
#include <wx/stattext.h    
#include <wx/gdicmn.h    
#include <wx/font.h    
#include <wx/colour.h    
#include <wx/settings.h    
#include <wx/textctrl.h    
#include <wx/sizer.h    
#include <wx/statline.h    
#include <wx/bitmap.h    
#include <wx/image.h    
#include <wx/icon.h    
#include <wx/button.h    
#include <wx/dialog.h    

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Class MainDialogBase
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class MainDialogBase : public wxDialog
{
    private:

    protected:
        wxStaticText* m_staticText3;
        wxStaticText* m_staticText1;
        wxTextCtrl* m_textCtrl1;
        wxStaticText* m_staticText4;
        wxTextCtrl* m_textCtrl2;
        wxStaticText* m_staticText6;
        wxStaticText* m_staticText5;
        wxTextCtrl* m_textCtrl3;
        wxStaticText* m_staticText7;
        wxTextCtrl* m_textCtrl4;
        wxStaticLine* m_staticLine;
        wxButton* m_button1;
        wxButton* m_button2;

        // Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
        virtual void OnCloseDialog( wxCloseEvent& event ) { event.Skip(); }


    public:

        MainDialogBase( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, const wxString& title = wxEmptyString, const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size =     wxSize( 400,300 ), long style = wxCLOSE_BOX|wxDEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE );
        ~MainDialogBase();

};
```

gui.cpp:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// C++ code generated with wxFormBuilder (version Oct 26 2018)
// http://www.wxformbuilder.org/
//
// PLEASE DO *NOT* EDIT THIS FILE!
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "gui.h"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

MainDialogBase::MainDialogBase( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size, long style ) : wxDialog( parent, id, title, >pos, size, style )
{
    this->SetSizeHints( wxSize( -1,-1 ), wxDefaultSize );

    wxBoxSizer* mainSizer;
    mainSizer = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

    wxBoxSizer* bSizer8;
    bSizer8 = new wxBoxSizer( wxHORIZONTAL );

    wxBoxSizer* bSizer2;
    bSizer2 = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

    m_staticText3 = new wxStaticText( this, wxID_ANY, _("Patient's data"), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize( 105,-1 ), 0 );
    m_staticText3->Wrap( -1 );
    m_staticText3->SetFont( wxFont( 10, wxFONTFAMILY_SWISS, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_BOLD, false, wxT("Sans") ) );

    bSizer2->Add( m_staticText3, 0, wxALL, 5 );

    wxBoxSizer* bSizer3;
    bSizer3 = new wxBoxSizer( wxHORIZONTAL );

    m_staticText1 = new wxStaticText( this, wxID_ANY, _("First Name:"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    m_staticText1->Wrap( -1 );
    bSizer3->Add( m_staticText1, 0, wxALL, 5 );

    m_textCtrl1 = new wxTextCtrl( this, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    bSizer3->Add( m_textCtrl1, 0, wxALL, 5 );


    bSizer2->Add( bSizer3, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );

    wxBoxSizer* bSizer4;
    bSizer4 = new wxBoxSizer( wxHORIZONTAL );

    m_staticText4 = new wxStaticText( this, wxID_ANY, _("Last Name:"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    m_staticText4->Wrap( -1 );
    bSizer4->Add( m_staticText4, 0, wxALL, 5 );

    m_textCtrl2 = new wxTextCtrl( this, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    bSizer4->Add( m_textCtrl2, 0, wxALL, 5 );


    bSizer2->Add( bSizer4, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );


    bSizer8->Add( bSizer2, 1, 0, 5 );

    wxBoxSizer* bSizer5;
    bSizer5 = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

    m_staticText6 = new wxStaticText( this, wxID_ANY, _("Doctor's data"), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize( 105,-1 ), 0 );
    m_staticText6->Wrap( -1 );
    m_staticText6->SetFont( wxFont( 10, wxFONTFAMILY_SWISS, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_BOLD, false, wxT("Sans") ) );

    bSizer5->Add( m_staticText6, 0, wxALL, 5 );

    wxBoxSizer* bSizer6;
    bSizer6 = new wxBoxSizer( wxHORIZONTAL );

    m_staticText5 = new wxStaticText( this, wxID_ANY, _("First Name:"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    m_staticText5->Wrap( -1 );
    bSizer6->Add( m_staticText5, 0, wxALL, 5 );

    m_textCtrl3 = new wxTextCtrl( this, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    bSizer6->Add( m_textCtrl3, 0, wxALL, 5 );


    bSizer5->Add( bSizer6, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );

    wxBoxSizer* bSizer7;
    bSizer7 = new wxBoxSizer( wxHORIZONTAL );

    m_staticText7 = new wxStaticText( this, wxID_ANY, _("Last Name:"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    m_staticText7->Wrap( -1 );
    bSizer7->Add( m_staticText7, 0, wxALL, 5 );

    m_textCtrl4 = new wxTextCtrl( this, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    bSizer7->Add( m_textCtrl4, 0, wxALL, 5 );


    bSizer5->Add( bSizer7, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );


    bSizer8->Add( bSizer5, 1, 0, 5 );


    mainSizer->Add( bSizer8, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );


    mainSizer->Add( 0, 0, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );

    m_staticLine = new wxStaticLine( this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxLI_HORIZONTAL );
    mainSizer->Add( m_staticLine, 0, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5 );

    m_button1 = new wxButton( this, wxID_ANY, _("Record Data"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    mainSizer->Add( m_button1, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND, 5 );

    m_button2 = new wxButton( this, wxID_ANY, _("List"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    mainSizer->Add( m_button2, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND, 5 );

    wxBoxSizer* bSizer9;
    bSizer9 = new wxBoxSizer( wxHORIZONTAL );


    mainSizer->Add( bSizer9, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );


    this->SetSizer( mainSizer );
    this->Layout();

    this->Centre( wxBOTH );

    // Connect Events
    this->Connect( wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, wxCloseEventHandler( MainDialogBase::OnCloseDialog ) );
}

MainDialogBase::~MainDialogBase()
{
    // Disconnect Events
    this->Disconnect( wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, wxCloseEventHandler( MainDialogBase::OnCloseDialog ) );

}
```

I also have the following inherited class:

inheritedgui.h:

```
#ifndef __inheritedgui__
#define __inheritedgui__

/**
@file
Subclass of MainDialogBase, which is generated by wxFormBuilder.
*/

#include "gui.h"

//// end generated include

/** Implementing MainDialogBase */
class inheritedgui : public MainDialogBase
{
    protected:
        // Handlers for MainDialogBase events.
        void OnCloseDialog( wxCloseEvent& event );
    public:
        /** Constructor */
        inheritedgui( wxWindow* parent );
    //// end generated class members

};

#endif // __inheritedgui__
```

inheritedgui.cpp:

```
#include "inheritedgui.h"

inheritedgui::inheritedgui( wxWindow* parent )
:
MainDialogBase( parent )
{

}

void inheritedgui::OnCloseDialog( wxCloseEvent& event )
{
// TODO: Implement OnCloseDialog
}
```

Could you please tell me how to get text entered in `m_textCtrl1` and assign it to a string variable when `m_button1` is pressed?

I'm trying to port a simple program from JavaFX to C++, the program mainly takes user input (from `wxTextCtrl` controls) and assigns the input to string variables, so then I can show the values stored in the variables in a messagebox when `m_button2` is pressed.

I've been doing some google searches, but C++ is getting a bit difficult for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m_textCtrl1` is a [`wxTextCtrl`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_text_ctrl.html), which has a [`GetValue()`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_text_entry.html#af234557ffcbfefb3ea45358c4f2a5283) method that returns a [`wxString`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_string.html), which in turn has a [`ToStdString()`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_string.html#a3c764622c960389c4d8c9e21e13bddc7) for converting to a `std::string`:

```cpp
std::string s = m_textCtrl1->GetValue().ToStdString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

@etcCoder,

If you pan to use messagebox function from wxWidgets you dont need to convert the string to std::string - wxMessageBox() accepts wxString.

Thank you.